# Connecting Windows 7 to NT4 domain?

Tags: windows-7, domain, windows-nt-4

My office domain is NT4, but I have a windows 7 laptop.  I've been told that I won't be able to log on.  Does anyone know a work around for this?

They're planning to upgrade to Windows 2003, but that could be a little while.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/9e09b926-a23a-4351-ba76-0b960c0819a2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 cannot joint an NT4 domain.

The only solution would be to join the domain from within XP Mode.

Comment: So, you can go into XP mode and connect to the domain from there?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 is looking for an Active Directory domain, which NT4 does not have. It is not supported and I don't see any sort of patch available. The lowest possibility is a Windows 2000 Active Directory domain. I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but it looks like you'll have to wait around for Win2K3.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft made it virtually impossible to join a Windows 7 machine to a NT 4.0 Domain.  So your best bet it is either to boot in Win Xp mode or wait on the Server 2003.....Sorry.